# Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' using ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ckeditor4.x

I have downloaded the ckeditor4 via online builder and put the file in public folder in my project. I have the cheditor4-vue integration, but want to use the local editor instead of the CDN, so I followed the documentation and put the `:url-editor` in the ckeditor html tag and put the path to the `ckeditor.js` file in `editorConfig`. Now when I run my application I get the error massage `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` in the console. Could it be that the app is serving index.html instead of the ckeditor.js that I am pointing with my path?

One more thing, if I put the path to the ckeditor.js file in the browser, I get the content of it, like I would expect the app to do.

Comment: Please share more details. Why not check which file is loaded there?

Comment: Your diagnosis sounds right; have you inspected the request in the dev tools' network tab yet?

Comment: @ChrisG I have and the requests go to the desired path. I get 304 not modified on the http://localhost:8080/ckeditor/ckeditor.js get request.

Comment: Not sure what's happening, might be a caching issue. Have you tried force-reloading the page / clearing site data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error message before

Are you using plugin named `image2`?

```
extraPlugins: "image2,..."
```

If you did, remove `image2` and change plugin from here: https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/image2

Add plugin like this way:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal(
        "image2",
        "/static/xxx/image2/plugin.js"
      );
```

...and dont use ckeditor default imageUpload plugin

Its work for me. No more error messages after this.

Sorry. My english so badly.

Hope this helps!